How to use otherwise gStyle in Angular 17
I am a beginner in Angular,
when I try the [ngStyle] directive with Angular 17, it does nothing, in fact it makes my DOM disappear. I wonder if we replaced the [ngStyle] directive with something else
I want to modify the style of a DOM from a directive
